# Swap base class at runtime?

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic

I know it had been asked a very long time ago, but no answers were really helpful, C# changed a lot since then and my problem is a bit different.

I'm in an environment that allows custom DLL loading, so people can add their content to the running program, let's say, submodules, but of course it comes at costs of some restrictions.

(Edited the example)

Example, none of this code exists

```
Public abstract class Car
{
    int tires=4;
    string color;

    public Car(string c){
        color = c;
    }
}

public class SportCar : Car{
    int doors = 3;
    int maxspeed=100;

    public void changeSpeed(int i){
        maxspeed = i;
    }
}

public class Ferrari : Car{
    string model = "Ferrari";
}
```

What i want to have after is

```
public ClassResult{
    int tires=4;
    string color;
    int doors = 3;
    int maxspeed=100;
    string model = "Ferrari";

    public ClassResult(string c){
        color = c;
    }
    public void changeSpeed(int i){
        maxspeed = i;
    }
}
```

So i asked for inheritance cause shown like this the problem is solved really easily if you have control over the code and can rewrite it. But i do not.
The only thing i can do is post process it to have the end result.

So changing at runtime the mother class of Ferrari or SportCar in the example would solve it, as it would be a classic inheritance but it might be another way.
Currently how i handle the issue is by discarding one of the child classes, but it's not really satisfying and may lead to other issues.

What exact control i have, is a class over all of those, that contain a collection of added classes. And i call some methodes inside of them that they are all supposed to implement. (That's why they all inherit the same base class)

Hope it's clearer this way.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by swapping base class? Seems like XY problem.

Comment: I want to swap the base class of one of the two derived class to make them inherit one another. No its not a XY problem.

Comment: Why do you need this inheritance? There is something you take it as granted but others don't.

Comment: I'll assume you have to provide some kind of plugin mechanisms for users. Then you can't control how users define a class. An well defined interface for extracting data from user's extended class should be enough. You don't need to take care of any implementation. @Davey van Tilburg 's example could be declared as an interface as well.

Comment: Yes it's close to a plugin mechanisms.
How should i extract datas from used extended class? I'm not sure reflection would allow this even if i can get property and method list.

Comment: You did not explain your use case. I'll guess use case is just a bunch of raw data ( int, double, string ..etc). You may define a generic data `Field` with name and value. Create an Interface `GetData` to get a list of `Field`. If you want more specific suggestion, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look in the direction of composition instead of inheritance.

Based on your example code, I would suggest the following composition:
(PS. this is just pseudo code to get the point across for composition, I typed it here, there are probably some build errors :p)

```
public class Car
{
    public List<CarModule> Modules;

    public InvokeMethod(string methodName)
    {
        Module moduleWithMethod = Modules.FirstOrDefault(m => m.HasMethod(methodName));

        moduleWithMethod.InvokeModuleMethod(methodName);
    }
}

public abstract class CarModule
{
    protected abstract Dictionary<string,Action> _moduleMethods;

    public bool HasMethod(string methodName) => _moduleMethods.Keys.Contains(methodName);

    public void InvokeModuleMethod(string methodName)
    {
        _moduleAction[methodName].Invoke()
    }
}

public sealed CarMovement : CarModule
{
    int _speed = 5;
    const int _maxSpeed = 100;

    private Dictionary<string,Action> _moduleMethods = 
    {
        ["ToMaxSpeed"] = () => ToMaxSpeed()
    }

    private void ToMaxSpeed()
    {
        _speed = maxSpeed;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestCase()
    {
        var speedingCar = new Car();
        speedingCar.Modules.Add(new CarMovement());

        speedingCar.InvokeMethod("ToMaxSpeed");
    }
}
```

Ofcourse I would not suggest using the Action type as a value for the dictionary, but rather use the command pattern to encapsulate the behaviours. Or something like that. But hopefully this gets you somewhere

Comment: I do not post any code because there is none. Like i said it's community DLL share issue. So you have base classes and people can extend from it and replace the base one with the new they made. The issue is you can have at the same time two people extending from the base class and submitting theirs. I do not put an XY i thought about the problema a lot and that's the only way i thought it could work.
I do not have control over the base class, i do not have control over the child classes. The only control i have is manage them. Currently i simply discard one, and that not what i want.

Comment: But if you have a way to add the onctent of one class to the other without exending i'm fine. Like i said it's not XY problem, but it's quite tricky, or i wouldn't post on this site.

Comment: @Salminar I could not make up from your question that you are not in control of the base class. From your wording, i'd say you are. So maybe that would be helpful to add what your position is and what you are trying to achieve for you, not this abstract situation you've sketched that seems to be from the package holders point of view

Comment: @Salminar Do you want two people to be able to extend the same base class at the same time? Then you need a different language because that is not possible in C#, but it is for example possible in C. C# would only be able to do this through composition, but that requires design and work

Comment: Edited the first post for a clearer example. If it's not possible well it's not. But wanted to have at least some clues if i could workaround the issue.

Comment: @Salminar Have a look at my updated answer, does this help?

Comment: It helps a bit but not sure i can implement it. Will try and think if i could make it work or adapt in a way or another. Thanks for the help and your time anyway.